# MySQL Server Gone

Tags: php, mysql, web-crawler

I try to store data into database. But I got "MySQL server gone away" error. Anyone can help me to find out my Error?

Actually this is one of the Basic PHP crawler. I'm beginner of this one. So Help me!!!

Connection.php :

```
<?php
$hostname_TestConnection = "******";
$database_TestConnection = "*******";
$username_TestConnection = "*******";
$password_TestConnection = "********";
$TestConnection = mysqli_connect($hostname_TestConnection, $username_TestConnection, $password_TestConnection) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($TestConnection),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

Index.php:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/TestConnection.php');
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');  

ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', -1);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', -1);

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
 function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType,  $TestConnection, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
  $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
}

$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ?  mysqli_real_escape_string($TestConnection, $theValue) :  mysqli_escape_string($TestConnection, $theValue);

switch ($theType) {
 case "text":
   $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
   break;    
 case "long":
 case "int":
   $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
   break;
 case "double":
   $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
   break;
 case "date":
   $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
   break;
 case "defined":
   $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
   break;
 }
 return $theValue;
 }
}

$target_url = "***";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html_sub_page = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($target_url);

//Declare elements {......}

//Retrieve latest ID from table {....}

//Main Page content {....}

//Sub Page content {....}

//Insert Into DB

if($flag == 1)
{
    for($i = 0 ; $i < $counter ; $i++)
    {

    $latestid ++;
    $guid .= $latestid;
    $post_name = $latestid.$post_name;

    $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO test_posts (post_author, post_date, post_date_gmt, post_content, post_title, post_excerpt, post_status, comment_status, ping_status, post_password, post_name, to_ping, pinged, post_modified, post_modified_gmt, post_content_filtered, post_parent, guid, menu_order, post_type,post_mine_type, comment_count) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($post_author, "int", $TestConnection),
                       GetSQLValueString($post_date, "date", $TestConnection),
                       GetSQLValueString($post_date_gmt, "date", $TestConnection),
                       GetSQLValueString($post_title_array[$i], "text", $TestConnection),
                       GetSQLValueString($post_title_array[$i], "text", $TestConnection),
                       GetSQLValueString($post_excerpt, "text", $TestConnection),
                       GetSQLValueString($post_status, "text", $TestConnection),
                       GetSQLValueString($comment_status, "text", $TestConnection),
                       GetSQLValueString($ping_status, "text", $TestConnection),
                       GetSQLValueString($post_password, "text", $TestConnection),
                       GetSQLValueString($post_name, "text", $TestConnection),
                       GetSQLValueString($to_ping, "text", $TestConnection),
                       GetSQLValueString($pinged, "text", $TestConnection),
                       GetSQLValueString($post_modified, "date", $TestConnection),
                       GetSQLValueString($post_modified_gmt, "date", $TestConnection),
                       GetSQLValueString($post_content_filtered, "text", $TestConnection),
                       GetSQLValueString($post_parent, "int", $TestConnection),
                       GetSQLValueString($guid, "text", $TestConnection),
                       GetSQLValueString($menu_order, "int", $TestConnection),
                       GetSQLValueString($post_type, "text", $TestConnection),
                       GetSQLValueString($post_mine_type, "text", $TestConnection),
                       GetSQLValueString($comment_count, "int", $TestConnection));

  mysqli_select_db($TestConnection,$database_TestConnection);
  $Result1 = mysqli_query($TestConnection, $insertSQL) or die(mysqli_error($TestConnection));

  $post_name = "-revision-v1"; 
  $guid = '****';
  echo "<br>Data ". ($i+1) . "succssfully inserted Into DataBase";
  //sleep(3);
 }
}

mysqli_free_result($RetrieveLatestID);
mysqli_close($TestConnection);
?>
```

Comment: *"MySQL server gone away" error* and the real mysqli error says?

Comment: Only i got "MySql Server gone away".

Answer (score 1):

from [Link](http://piwik.org/faq/troubleshooting/faq_183/)

The MySQL server has gone away (error 2006) has two main causes and solutions:

- Server timed out and closed the connection. To fix, check that “wait_timeout” mysql variable in your my.cnf configuration file is large enough.
- Server dropped an incorrect or too large packet. If mysqld gets a packet that is too large or incorrect, it assumes that something has gone wrong with the client and closes the connection. To fix, you can increase the maximal packet size limit “max_allowed_packet” in my.cnf file, eg. set max_allowed_packet = 128M, then sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart.

you have more complete information about the problem [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html)

Comment: How to check out wait_timeout and max_allowed_packet = 128M ? I'm using 000webhost .com (Free Hosting for testing).